# Inactive record types are selectable when creating a new record?

Tags: record-type

I am currently trying to update my org's record type structure and in the process we are removing/deactivating old record types. However, after marking them inactive, they are still available in the options when creating a new record. At what places can you control access to record types? We are currently using custom profiles with a permission sets.

Comment: Is the new page overridden with a visualforce page?

Comment: based on another post similar to this one, the record type dissapeared afeter a couple of hours from the selection. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119429/how-to-deactivate-record-types

Comment: @glls We have another environment that we deactivated the record types inyesterday and they are still available in that environment.

Comment: kk, good oto know =P, might want to add this to your description to avoid closing as duplicate or so other peeps can better help you.

Comment: @RahulSharma How do I check if the Record type selection page is overriden by a visual force page? I don't think it is due to the URL not having /apex/ in it.